# unix - multi monitor taskbar

Tags: multiple-monitors, unix, taskbar, arch-linux

Is there a way to expand (or mirror) the taskbar to a 2nd monitor on Arch Linux. My problem right now is that I open a program on taskbar 1 and move the windows to the second monitor. If I minimize the window I need to go back to taskbar 1, to open it again.

Desktop environment: Cinnamon 3.0.7

Comment: Find out which Desktop environment do you use and add this info to the question - much higher chance someone might help you then.

Comment: Done...I am using Cinnamon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used Cinnamon, but it looks like adding another taskbar is pretty straight forward.

First, we need to add another panel. Go to the panel settings, accessible by right clicking on your existing panel and then 'panel settings'. In general options, click 'Add new panel' and click where you want the other taskbar.

Then, you can add a taskbar applet by right clicking on the new panel, going to 'add applets to panel' and adding a 'window list'

Comment: That worked...I knew there must be an easy solution. ;) Thanks!